# javascript adodb stream error cant create object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I try create ActiveX Object with JavaScript in IE10:

```
try {
stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
}
catch(e){
alert(e.name + ': ' + e.message); 
}
```

and have error: 
Error: can't create object by object's server( i translate this from Russian, may be a litle other ).

I enable all ActiveX policies in ie properties and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX Compatibility{00000566-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}\Compatibility Flags=0

Does anybody know what i do wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`ADODB.Stream` can write to the local disk.

Due to sandbox security any interaction with the file system from within a web page is forbidden, so Internet Explorer cannot let you create such unsafe ActiveX objects.

If you want to use HTML+JavaScript as a tool to create a local application (instead of a web page), you can use an [HTML Application (HTA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here all ActiveX objects are allowed.